# IP VLANS and SUBNETS on Cisco and PFSENSE

Tags: cisco, vlan, subnet, pfsense

i have a PFSENSE router and a layer 3 cisco switch, the pfsense router connects to the switch on port 1 with the IP address of 192.168.1.2 and the router is 192.168.1.1

I have a vlan that i created called VLAN10 and I have the ip address on the vlan of 192.168.2.1, but the issue is that the vlan cannot connect to the internet

Routing has been enabled and should forward all data to 192.168.1.1 (the router)

But then i guess if the switch is sending data on the 192.168.3.X subnet then the subnet on the router (192.168.1.X) then it wont know what to do with it, in PFSENSE do i have to have new subnets assigned that are the same as the ones on the vlans?

I have not found anything online with my issue, please please can someone help me out!?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your Cisco L3 switch is acting as a router between various LAN segments.
pfSense has to be made aware of the 192.168.3.0/24 network and any other LAN segment, to do the right thing™.

Please register your Cisco L3 switch as a gatweway in pfSense.
Then add a static route to pfSense, for the network 192.168.3.0/24, with gateway 192.168.1.2, your Cisco switch.

One final step: in pfSense, packets from 192.168.3.0/24 leaving the firewall have to be source NATted with pfSense WAN address.
Go to Firewall/NAT/Outbound, and add a rule to source NAT packets from 192.168.3.0/24.

Comment: I am on another account, so I understand how to add it as a gateway but then how do i add a static route?

Comment: Please go to System → Routing → Static Routes, then +Add.

Write the network address in the Destination Network field, for example 192.168.3.0/24, and then choose your Cisco L3 switch IP address from the gateway dropdown, finish with Save.